# Quadrilateral Intersection 4 points

Tags: c#, rotation, geometry

[Rectangle Possibilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAHhZ.png)

I am trying to figure out if 2 rectangles that are rotated are intersecting.

The image(Rectangle Possibilities) shows examples of intersecting rectangle possibilities. The information that I know about each rectangle is the 4 vertices.

Comment: It’s easier if you perform the calculation with one rectangle relative to the other.  That is, take one rectangle in object space with no rotation but apply the rotation to the other

Comment: @RufusL that won't be accurate for rotated rectangles.  You'll just end up with over-sized bounding box tests

Comment: @MickyD ah, good point! deleted :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Powerfule method of checking whether two convex polygons do intersect is using [Separating Axes Theorem](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169). [Yet more description](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf).

[image]

It is rather simple (and fast) for rectangles.

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the two rectangles so that one becomes axis parallel, and check non-interference of the two axis-aligned bounding boxes. Then repeat with the second. This is necessary and sufficient to guarantee no overlap.

[image]